# Finding datetime from a string C#

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

Say I got a string that looks like this D1011608201313

The first part is random letters and the medium part is a date formatted like dd/mm/yyyy and the ladder an id for a record. However the first part can be pretty much random

Like [Random String][DateTime][ID], how would I find the placement of the datetime. The length of the random string, is about 4 to 8 characters.

If I can find the datetime, it should be pretty straight forward from there :)

Comment: Has your id always the same length? Can't you start from the end of the string?

Comment: i guess the id can be any number of digits? and the random dstring may contain numbers? then its impossible because there would be ambiguous strings

Comment: Is the record id part always the same length?  Either that or the first part probably has to be a fixed length, delimited from the date/time, or otherwise there needs to be some way to tell them apart (is the random string always letters?).

Comment: Will all of the strings have dates from the 21st century?

Comment: Yes, the dates are from this month. THe ids varies from one digit to five.

Comment: Your example could be interpreted as `D 10/11/6082 01313`. You could try all the possibilities and see which are sensible/this month.

Comment: if the dates are always from this month & this year, you might want to search for `DateTime.Today.Year`, in this example: `2013`.

Comment: What if I read it from behind?

Comment: This format of input will always be ambiguous.  If I were you I would try very hard to get it changed - for example to put a space between the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this RegEx supposing the date is in DDMMYYYY format, and the dates are in the year range of 1900-2099, but there will be some probability for ambiguity. I also updated this to be based off your comment in your question that the dates are from the current month.

```
public static void Main()
{ 
  // Leaves room for ambiguity if the random prefix or index suffix look 
  // like dates as well.
  var pattern = "((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)[0-9]{2}))";

  // Or, I see in your comment that the dates are from the current month. 
  // If so then this decreases the probability of a false match. You could
  // use the following pattern instead:
  var year =  DateTime.Today.Year;
  var month  = string.Format("{0:00}", DateTime.Today.Month);
  pattern = "((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(" + month + ")(" + year + "))";        

  var str = "D1011608201313";
  var matches = Regex.Matches(str, pattern);
  if (matches.Count == 0) return;

  var groups = matches[0].Groups;     
  int d, m, y;
  int.TryParse(groups[2].Value, out d);
  int.TryParse(groups[3].Value, out m);
  int.TryParse(groups[4].Value, out y);
  var date = new DateTime(y, m, d);
  Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

Detailed breakdown of the RegEx (from RegexBuddy):

```
((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)[0-9]{2}))

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])((19|20)[0-9]{2}))»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])»
      Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «0[1-9]»
         Match the character “0” literally «0»
         Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
      Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[12][0-9]»
         Match a single character present in the list “12” «[12]»
         Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
      Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «3[01]»
         Match the character “3” literally «3»
         Match a single character present in the list “01” «[01]»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(0[1-9]|1[012])»
      Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «0[1-9]»
         Match the character “0” literally «0»
         Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
      Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «1[012]»
         Match the character “1” literally «1»
         Match a single character present in the list “012” «[012]»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «((19|20)[0-9]{2})»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 5 «(19|20)»
         Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «19»
            Match the characters “19” literally «19»
         Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «20»
            Match the characters “20” literally «20»
      Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
         Exactly 2 times «{2}»
```

Comment: Note that this could fail on day 19 or 20 of any month, with the random string ending in digits that happen to appear date-like. But given the lack of restrictions, you can't do anything about that.

Comment: @Hans, true, unless he knows the specific ID in each case beforehand which I think is unlikely. We can reduce greatly the probability of a false match though. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If at least ID is known beforehand, you can guarantee to find it through a Regex

```
string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"^.*(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(20[0-9][0-9])" + ID + @"$", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture individual parts of the string in RegEx capture groups and reference them individually.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("D1011608201313",@".*([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4}).{2}$");
if (matches.Count!=0)
{
    var match = matches[0];
    var year = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[3].Value);
    var month = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
    var day = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    var result = new DateTime (year,month,day); 
}
```